# How to configure pigpiod to prevent being affected by aplay

Tags: gpio, pigpio, audio-playback

I'm using the pigpiod daemon and Python to output IR signals. I'm using raspbian jessie and rpi 3 model b gpio22 to output to leds.

After starting the daemon by `sudo pigpiod`, it works fine and outputs the signals to the IR leds. However, anytime after I play a wav file using `aplay`, the IR signals generated by the Python script gets outputted to audio out instead.

I saw this [previous question similar to mine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15155/gpio-affected-by-audio-playback) about gpio and audio playback. I tried using `sudo pigpiod -t 0` to separate the two but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way for pigpiod to not be affected by audio playback?

Comment: Which model of Raspberry Pi are you using ? Which GPIO pins are your IR leds connected to ?

Comment: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. Output to GPIO22. Updated my post to include this info

Comment: Are you playing your wav file through analogue audio (3.5mm socket) or hdmi audio ?

Comment: Through the 3.5mm jack